# Does it make sense to Favourite a Question you created?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

Is this just a redundant act, or are there differences?

Comment: It puts you one step closer to the Favorite Question and Stellar Question badges ♪

Answer (score -1):

Well... It certainly helps you to keep track of your questions N yeah as Grace Note mentioned it gets you badges.

Comment: Your questions are already [listed in your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/454686#questions)

Comment: @Michael Aye, but as Jon points out in the question random closed this as a duplicate of, when you have hundreds of questions the favorites can help you find specific ones easier... provided you don't have an equally large number of favorites. But that's what `infavorites:mine user:me` is for, I s'pose.